# Why use wa / は marker with kyou / 今日？

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-は

Based on some research it seems like:

今日は新しい着物を着ました。

Is more correct than

今日新しい着物を着ました。

(Without wa subject marker)

Why is that? It doesn't seem like "today" is the subject of the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it seems like:
>
> 今日は新しい着物を着ました。
>
> Is more correct than
>
> 今日新しい着物を着ました。

Not really, the bottom one is perfectly correct. For example you'll probably find more examples of 昨日新しい着物を着ました than 昨日は新しい着物を着ました. The reason why you get 今日は more is just because people more often talk about what they did today. It's as if answering the unanswered question "What did you do today?" The "wa" here just signals they're talking about today's events, and this is a new topic of conversation (what happened today).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!